# Indicator Synapse keyboard shortcut

Tags: synapse

I'm trying to change Indicator Synapse keyboard shortcut using dconf-editor.

```
net -> launchpad -> synapse-project -> indicator
```

On shortcut i set

```
<Control>space
```

but nothing changes.

Notice that event the default keybind is not working (Super Alt space)

I am using ubuntu 13.10

Any ideas?

Comment: I am using 14.04 and none of keybinding is working.

Comment: Alt + F10 -> Works... Maybe you will need another F-Function Key, like f11 or f12. Just try.

Comment: @DiegoGarciaVieira Alt+F10  works, thanks. Any chance i can change it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue [Shortcut to activate synapse resets to Control-space every reboot](https://bugs.launchpad.net/synapse-project/+bug/1164868) and still pending. If you feel up to it, there is [a patch](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/149657029/synapse_fix_hotkey.diff).

Even if the shortcut is correctly saved in `$HOME/.config/synapse/config.json`, it won't works.

Comment: Synapse that mentioned in this question is actually indicator-synapse. It is like spotlight at Mac for linux, not like gnome do or launchy.

Answer (score 2):

There is a work around for this, using xdotool. This tool lets you simulate keyboard input and mouse activity, move and resize windows, etc. It does this using X11's XTEST extension and other Xlib functions.

Here, we are going to find the coordinates of the mouse, and emulate a mouse click on the synapse indicator using a command and set a shortcut key for the command.

**Step 1: Install xdotool.**

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

**Step 2: Move your mouse over the synapse icon and get mouse location**

```
xdotool getmouselocation
```

You should get output like this:

```
x:1105 y:14 screen:0 window:39845936
```

**Step 3: Add keyboard shortcut for indicator**

Go to `System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts.`

Click the + and enter the below command:

```
xdotool mousemove x y click 1 mousemove restore
```

Replace `x` and `y` with the values you got. Set the shortcut as `Ctrl + Space` Logout and Login again.

Voilà!

Answer (score 2):

I installed in `Ubuntu 16.04.3`, by the time I install ubuntu already had the ppa, so I simply installed by

`sudo apt-get install synapse`

The default shortcut was `ctrl + space`, only flaw was, settings (synapse) did not work.

Since I was using `ctrl + space` for some other purpose, I wanted to change it to `alt + ctrl + space`. I simply fixed it with a custom keyboard shortcut.

Go to custom shortcuts
`Setting -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts`. Click on `+`, give a name (Synapse) and command (`synapse`), then `Add`. That's it now you I can use my custom shortcut.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This could be a conflict with what you're telling ubuntu to do globally and what Synapse is trying to do with its own shortcut assignment. I would recommend trying to set the shortcut from within Synapse: click the dot on the right side of the search pop-up, open the preferences, and you can set the shortcuts there.

Answer (score -2):

It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. I just tried it and it works.